Add TLS Certificate in openshift container’s trusted CA root certificate store
I have a springboot application that connects to a mail server using TLS certificate.
I am trying to follow the third method in this article, but it is not working.
I made changes to load the certificate from the secret in the template file. We use Jenkins pipeline to run the deployment, and I am not seeing any errors when I run the deployment, but when the app tries to connect to the mail server, I am still getting the certificate error:

"javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target"


I am not sure if I put the volumeMount correctly, or if I am missing something.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
What I did so far is the following:

I imported the ca certificate (PEM) file into a generic secret on openshift, the secret called ca-cert-secret, and has a key with same name
I tried to change the kubernetes template for the DeployConfig to import the certificate from the secret as follow:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: my-app-runtime
labels:
  template: my-app-runtime
  app: my-app 
parameters:
- name: ENV_NAME
  description: environment level being created such as master,sys, qa, prd
- name: NAMESPACE
  description: namespace to use in generating artifacts
  
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    generation: 1
    labels:
      app: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
      environment: ${ENV_NAME}
    name: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
  spec:
    replicas: ${{REPLICAS}}
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
    strategy:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
      resources: {}
      rollingParams:
        intervalSeconds: 1
        maxSurge: 25%
        maxUnavailable: 25%
        timeoutSeconds: 600
        updatePeriodSeconds: 1
      type: Rolling
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
        labels:
          deploymentconfig: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
          environment:  ${ENV_NAME}
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: GC_MAX_METASPACE_SIZE
            value: '300'
          - name: JAVA_OPTS_APPEND
            value: ${JAVA_OPTS_APPEND}                                          
          image: ${REGISTRY_HOST}/${PROJECT_NAME}/${NAMESPACE}:${IMAGE_TAG}
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: ${{MEMORY_LIMIT}}
            requests:
              cpu: ${{CPU_REQUEST}}
              memory: ${{MEMORY_REQUEST}}
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
        dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
        restartPolicy: Always
        schedulerName: default-scheduler
        securityContext: {}
        terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ca-cert-volume
          mountPath: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca.crt
          subPath: ca.crt  
        volumes:
        - name: ca-cert-volume
          secret:
            secretName: ca-cert-secret          
    test: false
    triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange

- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: ${NAMESPACE}
      environment: ${ENV_NAME}
    name: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      deploymentconfig: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
    sessionAffinity: None
    type: ClusterIP
  status:
    loadBalancer: {}
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Route
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: ${NAMESPACE}
      environment: ${ENV_NAME}
    name: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
  spec:
    host: ${ROUTE_HOST}
    port:
      targetPort: 8080-tcp
    tls:
      termination: edge
    to:
      kind: Service
      name: ${NAMESPACE}-${ENV_NAME}
      weight: 100
    wildcardPolicy: None    


What is the key for the ca.crt file inside the secret? You wrote that it is the same as the secret name if I understood correctly? The subPath in volume mounts needs to match the key name of the file inside the secret.

You need to import the certificates into Java truststore for your application in order for certificate to be used by your Java app.
You can either configure the truststore and include it in your Docker image, or you can mount the truststore as volume and pass it to your Java app via JVM system parameters.
Guide on doing that can be found here or elsewhere on Google:
https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/how-to-import-public-certificates-into-javas-truststore-from-a-browser-a35e49a806dc
